# Facebook login via Firebase. Should I verify both Facebook access token and Firebase IdToken?

Tags: firebase-authentication, angularfire2

This is not exactly a problem; rather I would like to clarify Firebase authentication.

I build an Angular app and I use Firebase Authentication to sign in via Facebook (later with other providers too). Everything works fine. However, I need to verify access token. Since I get two tokens, one from Facebook and one from Firebase, should I verify both? Or verifying Firebase IdToken is enough?

Does Firebase "verify" Facebook (and other providers) access token?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Auth will verify the Facebook access token before they complete sign-in for that user and mint an ID token for that user. It is the whole point of using Firebase Auth. You don't need to manage different providers and their intricacies. They do it for you. You just get one standard credential (ID token) regardless of the underlying provider. You only need to verify that ID token.

You get the verification for free (they verify under the hood) with other Firebase Services (RTDB, Firestore, Storage). If you are using your own server, you can use [Firebase Admin SDK to verify the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).